# KeyError: 'AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME' When trying to deploy to Heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to deploy my Django website onto Heroku and Amazon S3. However, after I typed git push heroku master, I got this:

```
Counting objects: 4, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 408 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> Preparing static assets
remote:        Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
remote:        $ heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 52.0MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v10
remote:        https://article-django.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.    
To https://git.heroku.com/article-django.git
   070a1af..c4bbac5  master -> master
```

Then I did `heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput` and got this traceback:

```
Running `python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput` attached to terminal... up, run.8499
/app/static/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django   /core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/app/django_test/settings.py", line 142, in <module>
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in   __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'
```

I also have my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn django_test.wsgi
```

And this snippet of my settings.py file:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except Exception as e:
    print e.message 

if not DEBUG:
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/' % article-deanna 
    STATIC_URL = S3_URL
```

I committed all of the changes but I don't know why I still run into this error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` [environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) on Heroku.

Try the following (inserting the name of your S3 bucket):

```
heroku config:set AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=<YOUR BUCKET NAME>
```